# How to show animation in all the ngFor elements as it happens only for the first one

Tags: angular

The code shows text typing animation on {{slide.txt} but it only shows only for the first slide for the rest the text is always there. How to enable the animation to show on all instances of the slide.

```
//before ng onInit
          sliderPos = 0;

              slides = [
                {img: "theme/images/home01.jpg", txt: 'widsds psds'},
                {img: "theme/images/home02.jpg", txt: 'wis'},
                {img: "theme/images/home03.jpg", txt: 'with a respdsdsivr sdsdte'}
              ]
              slideConfig = {autoplay: true,"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1, speed:800, "autoplaySpeed": 5000, cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.250,  0.060, 0.050, 0.040)'};



//after OnInit       
    afterChange(event) {
     if( event.currentSlide == 0 ){
        this.sliderPos = 0;
      }
      if( event.currentSlide == 1 ) {
        this.sliderPos = 1;
      }
      if( event.currentSlide == 2 ) {
        this.sliderPos = 2;
      }
    }
```

html

```
    <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" class="lazy slider" 
              #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
              [config]="slideConfig" (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
                <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
                  <h1>Empower your business <span typingAnimation [typeSpeed]="50" (complete)="onComplete()">{{slide.txt}}</span></h1>
                  <figure><img src="{{slide.img}}" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
                </div>
              </ngx-slick-carousel>
```

Comment: I think your code implementation is true but animation is showing at the same time for all slides. Can you try to decrease typeSpeed and immediately go for second slide after page load to check is it true idea.

Comment: Yes you are right it does at the same time for all the slides.. So how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As we talked on comments you should make your slider container lazy loading. To do that change your html like that. I am not sure is this will work but if not when you share demo on stackblitz, I can try to help you more.

*component.html*

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" class="lazy slider" #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig" (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
    <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index" class="slide">
        <ng-container *ngIf="sliderpos == i">
            <h1>Empower your business 
        <span typingAnimation [typeSpeed]="50" (complete)="onComplete()">{{slide.txt}}</span>
      </h1>
      <figure><img src="{{slide.img}}" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
    </ng-container>
    </div>
</ngx-slick-carousel>
```